# Cannot find a parameter with this name: backgroundColor

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to change background color of a button. But it gives me "Cannot find a parameter with this name: backgroundColor" error.

```
 Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Yellow),
       ) {
         Text(
           text = "Button",
       )
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be because you are using Material 3, in which case the naming of parameters is different:

```
colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        containerColor = Color.Yellow,
        contentColor = // choose your color)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `android-jetpack-compose`, the Button component does not have a parameter called `backgroundColor`. You can change the background by wrapping the Button component inside a Box and setting the background colour for the Box:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Yellow)
        .padding(8.dp)
) {
    Button(
        onClick = { /* TODO */ },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Button")
    }
}
```